# Rails secrets in sunspot.yml - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-solr

For development and testing I'm using settings in secrets.yml as follows:

```
test:
  secret_key_base: another_really_long_string
  database:
    :name: your_test_db
    :username: postgres_user
    :password: awesome_secure_password
  solr:
    :username: solr_server_username
    :password: solr_server_password
```

This is fine in config/database.yml with such entries as this:

```
database: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:name] %>
```

But, in sunspot.yml, the following causes problems:

```
test:
  solr:
    hostname: http://<%= Rails.application.secrets[:solr][:username] %>:<%= Rails.application.secrets[:solr][:password] %>@hostname.domain
    port: 8080
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr
```

The end result of the non-working call to secrets in the hostname line is for any attempt to start rails in development, run tests, connect to the console &c. to give me this:

```
(erb):19:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Can anyone suggest why this seems to work for the database but not SOLR?

Comment: is this a typo `:name:`? it should be `name:`

Comment: I think rails app is not initialized when sunspot.yml is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. That would make sense, which probably means there's no way around but to use ENV in test as well as production.